# .app file not recognized by Appium

Tags: appium-ios, .app

I am trying to launch my app in Appium by providing the `.app` file of my app.
But its throwing an error message -

"Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object."

I took the `.app` file path from `Xcode`
 after building the project.
Has it anything to do with the build process ?

Comment: Anyone with any thoughts...pls pitch into the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

App should be Debug enabled and it should run on device. I think which you have taken (.app file) will work on Simulator not on device.

Answer (score 0):

1. app should be a debug build.
2. for ios bundle id is required and not package and activity name.